# Alternative Proof: How to show that a theory with arbitrarily large finite models has an infinite model without compactness or ultraproducts?

Tags: model-theory, alternative-proof

This question is taken from exercise 2.5.2 in David Marker's *Model Theory: An Introduction*.

The question is:

> Suppose that [a theory] $T$ has arbitrarily large finite models. Show
> that $T$ has an infinite model.

My first idea for how to prove this was to use an ultraproduct; the argument is shown below. One recommendation in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3862098) is to use compactness; this argument is also shown below. I'm curious if there are any other ways to prove this result.

**What are some alternative ways to prove that $T$ has an infinite model besides using compactness or ultraproduct?**

---

What follows is my attempt to prove this result using the two methods I listed.

---

**This is my attempt to prove this result using ultraproduct.**

The first idea that popped into my head for how to do this is to use the ultraproduct construction.

Let $a_1 < a_2 < \cdots $ be a strictly increasing sequence of positive integers.

Let $M_1, M_2, \cdots$ be a sequence of models of $T$ such that $|M_i| = |a_i|$.

Let $S$ be the set of all sequences of elements of $M_i$, i.e. sequences of the form $t_1, t_2, \cdots$ where $t_i \in M_i$.

I now define an equivalence relation $\simeq$.

$$ a \simeq b \iff (\exists n \mathop. \forall w > n \mathop. a_w = b_w) $$

For each function symbol $f$ in $T$, let the interpretation of $f$ be the componentwise application of $f$.

$$ f((t_1, t_2, \cdots), (t'_1, t'_2, \cdots), \cdots) = (f(t_1, t'_1, \cdots), f(t_2, t'_2, \cdots), \cdots) $$

Similarly, let $[\varphi]$ be $0$ if $\varphi$ is false and let $[\varphi]$ be $1$ if $\varphi$ is true.

Let $((t_1, t_2, \cdots), (t'_1, t'_2, \cdots), \cdots) \in R$ hold if and only if the following holds.

$$ \lim_{k \to \infty} [(t_k, t'_k, \cdots) \in R] = 1 $$

So, each function and relation symbol is defined on elements of $S$.

Let $S'$ be equal to $S / \simeq$. Note that $\simeq$ is a congruence with respect to the signature of $T$.

Let $M'$ be the model with universe $S'$ where each function and relation symbol of $T$ is defined by operating on canonical representatives of equivalence classes in $S'$.

---

**This is my attempt to prove this result using compactness.**

However, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3862086/if-a-theory-with-equality-has-arbitrarily-large-finite-normal-models-then-it-ha) suggests an approach using compactness.

Let $\varphi^n$ be a sentence that is true of a structure $M$ if and only if $|M| \neq n$, call $n$ the *index* of $\varphi^n$.

Consider the theory $T' = T \cup \{ \varphi^1, \varphi^2, \cdots \}$.

Suppose $T'_0$ is a finite subset of $T'$. Let $m$ be the largest index of any $\varphi^\mathbb{N}$, or $1$ if there are no sentences from $\varphi^\mathbb{N}$ in $T'_0$.

By hypothesis, $T$ has a model $M$ of a size strictly greater than $m$. $M$ is a model of $T'_0$ as well since its cardinality isn't excluded by any sentence in $T'_0$.

Since every finite subset of $T'$ has a model, by compactness $T'$ has a model, call it $N$.

$N$ is infinite since its cardinality is not equal to any positive integer.

Comment: Since compactness requires proof, and one of those proofs is via ultraproducts (not ultra*powers*, that's when the structures involved are all the same), this isn't really two different proofs.

Comment: The construction you wrote down is *not* an ultraproduct! (where's the ultrafilter?) It's the reduced product by the cofinite filter, and it does not produce a model of $T$ in general.

Comment: I thought that "eventually the same" defined an ultrafilter on the index set $\mathbb{N}$ ... I was trying to unfold the "ultra"filter in the definition of the equivalence relation ... the set of upwardly closed sets of $\mathbb{N}$ is just a filter?

Comment: Yes, it's just a filter. Can you think of a subset of the natural numbers such that neither it nor it's complement is upwards closed?

Comment: Yes, the evens. Thank you. Can I pick an arbitrary ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}$ or is my choice restricted by the particular sequence of finite models $M_1, M_2, \cdots$ in some way?

Comment: Any *non-principal* ultrafilter will do (as long as the sizes of the $M_i$ increase along the sequence). Note that an ultrafilter is non-principal if and only if it contains the cofinite filter. @RobertShore Note that the OP's sentences say that the model has size $\neq n$.  $T'$ looks consistent to me.

Comment: @RobertShore ... I meant $\varphi^n$ to mean that my model does *not* have exactly $n$ distinct elements. The argument might still fail but I don't think $T'$ is inconsistent.

Comment: I don't think you can prove this without (using or) proving a variant of the compactness theorem - the statement is more or less literally an instance of the compactness theorem, after all! As such, I'm voting to close this question as not well-posed.

Comment: In fact, I am inclined to think this particular instance probably does, in fact, imply the compactness theorem for countable sets of sentences (in ZF, say, but any reasonable background theory, really). If you just want a proof without explicitly invoking compactness or ultraproducts, you can just take any other proof of compactness (e.g. via Henkin constructions) and adapt it to this particular case.