# What happens if "equality of sets" is regarded as a defined concept instead of a primitive notion?

Tags: logic, set-theory, definition

Formulation 1 below is the one used in the classical set theory (used in the traditional mathematics), right?

> **Formulation 1**
> *Primitive notions:* set, be element of, equality.
> *Axiom:* A set $A$ is equal to a set $B$ if all elements of $A$ are elements of $B$ and vice-versa.

Instead of taking equality as a primitive notion, could it be considered a defined concept as in Formulation 2?

> **Formulation 2**
> *Primitive notions:* set, be element of.
> *Definition of equality:* We say that a set $A$ is "equal" to a set $B$ if all elements of $A$ are elements of $B$ and vice-versa.

From the mathematical point of view, it seems there is no difference. The theorems will be proved the same way, right?

Is there any context where Formulation 2 is considered wrong or not equivalent to Formulation 1?

Comment: In axiomatic set theory, #2 is exactly how it _is_ defined. The usual language of axiomatic set theory is just the language of first-order logic, plus one undefined relation “$\in$”.  The notation “$S=T$” is understood as nothing more than a convenient abbreviation for “$\forall x(x\in S\iff x\in T)$”.

Comment: @MJD: One cannot regard $S=T$ as a defined abbreviation for $\forall x. x\in S \leftrightarrow x\in T$ in ZF set theory. That simply does not sufficie to get the essential substitution property of equality.

Comment: @Z.A.K. So equality is neither a primitive notion nor a defined concept, right? It is a "previous thing" whose properties (such as, for example, substitution) are already known when we state the axiom of extensionality. Is this correct? What is he technical name for what I called “previous thing”?

Comment: @Z.A.K.Thanks for this and your comment below. I didn't appreciate this issue.

Comment: @Z.A.K.: Is that really the case even for a language as simplistic as $\{\in\}$? Is that the whole thing about Leibnizian equality?

Comment: @Pedro Equality *is* a primitive notion of first-order logic. There is another logic, called "first-order logic without equality" in which equality is not taken to be primitive. But standard set theories like ZFC are formulated in first-order logic, with equality as a primitive notion.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If one does not have equality as part of the underlying logic, then there is indeed a way of defining it inside set theory,

$x = y \overset{def}\Longleftrightarrow (\forall z(z \in x \iff z \in y) \land \forall  z (x \in z \iff y \in z))$

which of course is just a modification of extensionality: the new bit about *belonging* to exactly the same sets is just so that one is able to recover the substitution principle of equality

$\forall x,y (x = y \implies (\varphi(x) \iff \varphi(y)))$

for any $\varphi(-)$, from separation/comprehension, which I suppose is not possible using only

$x = y \overset{def}\Longleftrightarrow \forall z(z \in x \iff z \in y)$

edit: if one defines equality by that first phrase up there, then it only makes sense that the 'new', appropriate axiom of extensionality is/becomes

Ax.Ex.: $\forall x,y (\forall z(z \in x \iff z \in y) \iff \forall  z (x \in z \iff y \in z))$

Comment: So equality is neither a primitive notion nor a defined concept, right? It is a "thing that is part of the underlying logic" whose properties (such as, for example, substitution) are already known when we state the axiom of extensionality. Is this correct? What is the technical name for “things that are part of the underlying logic”?

Comment: Too many questions at once and a lot of confusion, so bear with me (por favor) as I try to piece things together: (1) Some (first order) theories simply *need* to assume equality as 'part of the logic': if, for example, a theory only has functional symbols (no relational symbols), then it has no hope to define equality (try to figure out why); on the other hand, a theory of arithmetic with a binary relational symbol for ordering can do it pretty much the same way we did here; (2) Equality *can* be, and most often *is*, taken as part of the underlying logic, and its "only" properties are [cont]

Comment: reflexivity and substitution: everything else (should) follows from these; (3) Equality does not depend, in any way, upon set theoretic extensionality: it makes sense in contexts where there's simply no notion of extensionality to begin with (again, think of purely functional theories); (4) I'm not sure there is a standard/canonical name for symbols that are taken as part of the logic, but I vaguely remember some people in model theory specifically calling them 'logical constants' because 'they are always interpreted the same way' (ufa!)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @ac15's answer, you can prove
$$\forall x\forall y (\forall  z (x \in z \iff y \in z)) \implies (\forall z(z \in x \iff z \in y))$$
from comprehension and pairing.  Assume $x, y$ are members of the same sets but don't have the same members.  w.l.o.g. we may assume there exists $t\in x\setminus y$.

By pairing
$$\forall x\forall y\exists Z (x\in Z\land y\in Z)\tag{1}$$
Let $Z_0$ be a $Z$ satisfying $(1)$ for the given $x,y$.

An instance of comprehension is
$$\forall s\forall Z\exists u(\forall p (p\in u\iff p\in Z\land s\in p))\tag{2}$$
Specializing $(2)$ to $s=t, Z=Z_0$ we get
$$\exists u(\forall p (p\in u\iff p\in Z_0\land t\in p))\tag{3}$$
Let $u_0$ be a $u$ satisfying $(3)$.  Then
$$\forall p (p\in u_0\iff p\in Z_0\land t\in p)\tag{4}$$

Now, from $(1)$, $x\in Z_0$ and from $(4)$, $x\in u_0$.  OTOH, since $t\not\in y$ then $y\not\in u_0$.  So there exists a set $u_0$ of which $x$ is a member and $y$ is not.  This contradicts the assumption about $x, y$.

So for an axiom of extensionality it's enough to take
$$\forall x\forall y (\forall z(z \in x \iff z \in y) \implies \forall  z (x \in z \iff y \in z))$$
with the other direction following from pairing and comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum to everything that's been said so far, $=$ actually does not need to be interpreted as meta-level sameness. You can make $=$ follow other rules and get a semantics for first-order logic that's equivalent to the standard one.

This is less convenient than just making $=$ meta-level sameness. And, if done, you need to talk about meta-level sameness anyway via [normal models](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3862086/). A normal model is just one where $=$ is interpreted as real sameness.

So, in a certain sense, sameness is unavoidable.

However, we can imagine taking **first-order logic without equality** and asking **what we would have to assume about a binary relation $=$ in order to get it to behave as closely as possible to equality**.

It must be a congruence with respect to every constant, function and relation symbol.

This condition can be imposed with some assumptions that can be encoded as first-order sentences.

1. $=$ is an equivalence relation.
2. For all constant symbols $c$, it holds that $[\forall x y](x = y \to (x = c \leftrightarrow y = c))$. (This is actually a consequence of $=$ being an equivalence relation, but is nice to call out explicitly)
3. For all relation symbols $R$ it holds that $[\forall \vec{x} \vec{y}](\vec{x} = \vec{y} \to (R(\vec{x}) \leftrightarrow R(\vec{y})))$, where $\vec{x} = \vec{y}$ abbreviaties $\vec{x}_1 = \vec{y}_1 \land \cdots \land \vec{x}_n = \vec{y}_n$
4. For all function symbols $f$ it holds that $[\forall \vec{x} \vec{y}](\vec{x} = \vec{y} \to f(\vec{x}) = f(\vec{y}))$.

The language of set theory has a single binary relation $\in$.

So, in a certain sense, extensionality alone doesn't nail down $=$ enough. We also need $=$ to be an equivalence relation and we need the following to hold:

$$ [\forall x y z w] ((x = y \land z = w) \to (x \in z \leftrightarrow y \in w)) $$

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** This answer is wrong, but I'll leave it here anyway because of the great comments of @Z.A.K.

You might be interested in first order logic and the ZF axioms of set theory, under which your Formulation 2 becomes the standard.

Equality becomes a logical notion. The [ZF axiom of extensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory#1._Axiom_of_extensionality) characterizes the notion of equality in set theory.

Comment: No, regarding $A=B$ as a definition/abbreviation for the fornula $\forall x. x\in A \leftrightarrow x\in B$ does not work. The equality symbol is treated in a special way in the usual syntax and semantics of first-order logic, and if you try to treat the axiom.of extensionality as if it were a definition, you lose some important theorems (e.g. most instances of substitution, see @ac15 's excellent anawer). One can work around this issue, but only by defining $A=B$ as an abbreviation for a _different_ formula: e.g. $\forall x. A\in x \leftrightarrow B\in x$ does the job.

Comment: Interesting, this is something I did not know. So if one does *not* assume the axiom of extensionality, I take it that there are models where the final statement of Chad's answer is false?

Comment: Indeed. By a [famous argument](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=163838) of Dana Scott, Extensionality does not follow from ZF-Extensionality. One can use this fact to construct models of ZF-Extensionality with two sets $x$ and $y$ that contain the same elements, but for which _some_ substitution implication $\varphi(x) \rightarrow \varphi(y)$ explicitly fails. In that model the set $\{z \in \{x,y\} \mid \varphi(z) \}$ defined by Pairing and Comprehension contains $x$, but not $y$. Thus, in such a model the final formula of Chad's answer fails to hold.

Comment: Thanks, that's great to know about.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a key issue here is whether it’s allowed that two *distinct* sets compare as equal (C++ programming analogy: two instances of the `std::complex` type, at different memory locations, which compare as equal because they represent the same complex number)

In normal set theory (and hence OP’s **Formulation 1**) I believe this is impossible by definition, c.f. Suppes, *Axiomatic Set Theory*, section 1.2:

> ‘=‘ is taken as the sign of identity. The formula ‘x=y’ may be read as ‘x is the same as y’, ‘x is identical with y’…it is understood that equality means sameness of identity.

Or more concisely [here](http://logic.stanford.edu/intrologic/extras/equality.html):

> If two terms are equal (i.e. they refer to the same object)

If the OP’s **Formulation 2** actually ***is*** intended to allow two distinct sets to compare as equal, then it would imply the possibility that:

- $a \in X$ and $b = a$, ***but*** $b \notin X$

which would be a very weird new kind of set theory.

But if that’s ***not*** the intent, then the two formulations seem equivalent to me (though **Formulation 1** seems a lot clearer)

Answer (score -4):

What's the definition of Primitive Notion? I'm inclined to say Set Equality is not a Primitive Notion if the latter is defined as the most primitive terms in an axiomatic system.

Any axiomatic system will have fundamental terms which can't be defined, otherwise you get an infinite regress. Further, you can't get more fundamental than the undefined terms. Consider defining Point, Set, and Plane in Euclidean Geometry.

In matters of set theory, we accept as undefined terms Set, Member/Element of. You can't get more primitive than that.

The question can be rephrased, is Set Equality as primitive as  "Set"?

Both Formulation 1 and Formulation 2 stipulate a relationship using undefined terms.  I'm thinking the need of stipulating the notion of Set Equality with those undefined terms necessarily implies the notion is less primitive than those basic terms. Thus we have Set Equality as a definition and not a Primitive Notion.

Other answers tell us that Set Equality can be represented as a modification of Extensionality, but Extensionality itself is stated in terms of more fundamental notions.

Definitions name a relationship between undefined terms necessarily specifying a subset of the fundamental structures involved.

Axioms establish relationships between fundamental entities without necessarily specifying a new term for entities.

So both Definitions and Axioms are less primitive than the undefined terms.

Theorems are proven using references to Definitions and Axioms, so they are less primitive than those.

So Set Equality is not among the most primitive notions in Set Theory, but is more primitive than any theorems.

I'm inclined to think Formulation 2 is unavoidable. Again, this all rests on the definition of "Primitive Notion".